# How to delete Many-To-Many Attribute from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I Have in DB Many-To-Many relation between 2 tables. And I'm using EF Code first from Db.

Table **Genres**:

```
public partial class Genres

    {
        public Genres()
        {
            Post = new HashSet<Post>();
        }

        public int GenresID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(90)]
        public string GenresName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(128)]
        public string GenresSlug { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200)]
        public string GenresDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Post { get; set; }
    }
```

Table **Post**:

```
public partial class Post
    {

        public Post()
        {
            Genres = new HashSet<Genres>();
        }

        public int PostID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(150)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [Column(TypeName = "text")]
        public string Description { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Publish Date")]
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Genres")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string GenresList { get; set; }   

        public virtual ICollection<Genres> Genres { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have Actually **Two Questions** :

1- **How** to Delete The Values From Table GenresPost which is created from this relation ? Only from the GenresPost I don't Want to Delete My Post Or Make It Affect from this.

2-In my **Genres** Table When I add a new Post I got the Genres from text field like this :

> Drama,Romance,Shoujo

and then i split them and add them, but they keep repeating in database and i need them to be unique , so when i add for example Drama there and add it again in other post , i want to check if it exists so i don't need to add it again .. and here is my code for this but it's not worked from me :

> post.GenresList contain the genres like this (Drama,Romance,Shoujo)

```
if (post.GenresList != null)
            {
                Collection<Genres> GenresPost = new Collection<Genres>();
                var s = post.GenresList.ToString();
                string[] newGenres = s.Split(',');

                foreach (var val in newGenres)
                {
                    var iTag = db.Genres.FirstOrDefault(t => t.GenresName == val);

                        if (iTag == null && val.Length > 1)
                        {

                            iTag = new Genres
                            {
                                GenresName = val.Trim(),
                                GenresSlug = val.MakeUrlFriendly2(),

                            };
                            db.Genres.Add(iTag);
                        }

                    GenresPost.Add(iTag);

                }
                post.Genres = GenresPost;
            }
```

Comment: How many genres can be for one post? Just one? So, for each post you have only one row in GenresPost table?

Comment: Well The Post Can be In Many Genres and The Genre Hold Many Posts!